# ListView DataBind Not Working When Updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding

I am having trouble DataBinding my ListView.

When I am trying to Update a single record in the ListView I call a stored procedure in the code behind using the UpdateCommand button inside the lsitview.

```
protected void LV_TicketProd_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true; //This is to cancel the default Update function to allow my stored procedure.
    int fail = DatabaseInteraction.UpdateTicketProduct(Int32.Parse(ChargeIDLabel.Text), Int32.Parse(TicketNumLabel.Text), Int32.Parse(ProductDDL.Text), Rate, HoursOrCubes);
    LV_TicketProd.DataBind();
}
```

Once the Update is complete I want to display the changes. But this isn't working. What is happening is the Update works correctly, but the record that was Updated stays in the UpdateTemplate just for that record. Any idea on how to change the template/view or get the data bind to work?

I am not using any xaml.

Comment: Please provide some more code, how you start ? any xaml involved...

Comment: I dont really know what other code I could include for this particular problem. Although i included the event handler the code is sitting in.